# How to Encrypt and Decrypt using Jasypt in Quarkus for database password

Tags: quarkus

How we can encrypt and decrypt database password in properties file using jasypt in Quarkus.
The decryption will be happens while loading or starting the application.
Please share your inputs or thoughts on this.

@chrisgleissner any help much be appreciated.

### application.properties

quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgre
quarkus.datasource.username=username
quarkus.datasource.password=encrypted pwd(encrypted needs to decrypt while loading application)

Comment: For security, this should be supported in Quarkus. Springboot supports ENC()

Answer (score 1):

You can create an implementation of io.smallrye.config.ConfigSourceInterceptor.
In the getValue method decrypt with Jasypt the property (or properties) you want.
Don't forget to register your implementation class as an SPI, META-INF/services/io.smallrye.config.ConfigSourceInterceptor.

More info on https://smallrye.io/docs/smallrye-config/main/index.html

Comment: Link does not work anymore.

Comment: Link seems to have changed but not that much.https://smallrye.io/smallrye-config/3.0.0/

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom credentials provider. The interface is:

```java
public interface CredentialsProvider {

    String USER_PROPERTY_NAME = "user";
    String PASSWORD_PROPERTY_NAME = "password";

    Map<String, String> getCredentials(String credentialsProviderName);

}
```

From the documentation:

> USER_PROPERTY_NAME and PASSWORD_PROPERTY_NAME are standard properties that should be recognized by any consuming extension that support username/password based authentication. It is required that implementations be valid @ApplicationScoped CDI beans.

Your encrypted password should be available by system properties or env variable for example.

Example:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
@Unremovable
public class MyCredentialsProvider implements CredentialsProvider {

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getCredentials(String credentialsProviderName) {

        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(USER_PROPERTY_NAME, "hibernate_orm_test");
        properties.put(PASSWORD_PROPERTY_NAME, decryptPassword());
        return properties;
    }

}
```

And in the application.properties set the credentials-provider as custom.

```
quarkus.datasource.credentials-provider=custom
```

You can check this section in the documentation guides: [custom credentials provider](https://quarkus.io/guides/credentials-provider#custom-credentials-provider)

Comment: Thanks for your response and i have bumped up the quarkus version  1.12.2.final version and there i have implemented the changes.

how we can read password from file system in quarkus. I have used below configuration but its unable to reading that location. Do you have any suggestions on this.

Ex:  

       username: sample_app
        password: FILE(/opt/pwd/app/appdb.pwd)---> but this location unable to read it and quarkus unable to handle the FILE(xxxxxx). Do you have any idea on this?
its giving password as FILE(/opt/pwd/app/appdb.pwd) instead of actual value.

Comment: Can you please post an entire example of what you are trying to do? Can you edit your question with some code and the application.properties?